# Sending Slack Message to channel from salesforce flow

Tags: salesforce, slack

I am trying to send a notification to slack channel through salesforce flow.

But I am getting this error

```
This error occurred when the slackPostMessage action tried 

to execute the Slack API method: chat.postMessage. 

Error: channel_not_found.
```

The slack channel exists.

I have provided the channel id.

What am I doing wrong?

My username in salesforce is different than my username in slack, is that why?

or do I need to invite bot to the channel?How to do that?

Here is the screenshot of the action in the flow
[image]